# Replace a character with \1

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to do something like the following. Let's say i have the following string:

```
"some string"
```

And i wanted to replace the space with a \1. However, wether i use single or double quote, i dont get the result:

```
"some string".gsub(" ", "\1") => "somestring"
"some string".gsub(" ", '\1') => "somestring"
"some string".gsub(" ", '\\1') => "somestring"
```

What i want is:

```
"some\1string"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only annoying because `\1` through `\9` are reserved for use in substitutions.

A possible solution is:

```
"some string".gsub(" ", '\\\\1')
```

It's kind of ugly, but it works.

An alternative is to use the block style where substitution isn't performed:

```
"some string".gsub(" ") { '\1' }
```

Remember that the output will be `"some\\1string"` because backslash is represented as `\\` inside a double-quoted string. If you print it out you will get a single backslash.

Comment: I imagined it would be a simple solution, just couldnt think of what. Thanks for that :).

Answer (score 2):

This is also possible:

```
s = "some string"

p s.split.join('\1') # "some\\1string"
```